# updating an attribute to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to update an attribute as `nil` if the passed param is the same.

For example `type` attribute can hold the integers say `1,2,3` if from the view I receive `params[:type]` as `1` and the type is also `1` I need to make it as `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

```
@my_obj = MyObject.find(params[:id])

if params[:type] == @my_obj.type
  @my_obj.update_attribute(:type, nil)
end
```

Comment: can't we test like if params[:type] ==  @my_obj.type
  @my_obj.update_attribute(:type, nil)
end

Comment: make your if condition `params[:type] == @my_obj.type` and it will work for any value.

Comment: Better to use `update_attributes!(:type => nil)` since that will call validations as well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best way to do this is something like

```
params[:your_object][:test] = nil if params[:your_object][:test] == @your_object.type
@your_object.update_attributes(params[:your_object])
```

(simple code: see the repetition of `params[:your_object]` -> that should be refactored)

You could also want to do it in two steps: first extract the type, and later update the attributes, but i think it is more work.

```
received_type = params[:your_object].delete(:type)
received_type = nil if received_type == @your_object.type
@your_object.update_attribute :type, received_type

#still do the rest of the update, without the type
@your_object.update_attributes(params[:your_object])
```

Hope this helps.